# How to detect a line break in Excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the carriage return\line break in various cells, by iterating over them and running the InStr function against the text in each of those cells. The below query is finding the line break correctly in most cells, but is failing in one of those cells.

The line break in those cells was added the same for all of them, and that is by hitting Alt+Enter.

Below is the function I am using:

```
InStr(startlocation, text, vbLf)
```

I also tried all of the below, but to no avail:

```
InStr(startlocation, text, Chr(10)) 'this seems to be identical in results to using vbLf
InStr(startlocation, text, Chr(13)) 'No results with this
InStr(startlocation, text, ALT + 10) 'I see this returning some results sometimes, not exactly sure for which character though
InStr(startlocation, text, vbCrLf) 'No results with this
```

Is there any other way to represent line break so I add it to my query?

Comment: Just for kicks have you tried printing the ascii value of each character?  For I = 1 to len(text)   Debug.print asc(mid(text,I,1))   Next I.  Put these statements on different lines.  Also I wouldn’t use “text” as a variable, it looks too much like a reserved word.

Comment: Where is your text coming from?  If the line breaks were entered in Excel using Alt+Enter they will be `vbLf` (Ascii 10)

Answer (score 1):

The line break in cells, which is created with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is a `vbLf`.

Therefore the following should work.

```
InStr(startlocation, text, vbLf)
```

If it doesn't work that means you did something else wrong.

If you have the following data in cell A1 (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `1` and `2`)

[image]

Then `InStr(1, Range("A1"), vbLf)` returns `2`.

---

For example you can use …

```
Dim ArrLines As Variant
ArrLines = Split(Range("A1"), vbLf)
```

to split these lines into an array like …

- `ArrLines(0)` is `1`
- `ArrLines(1)` is `2`
- `ArrLines(2)` is `3`

Answer (score 0):

As others have confirmed, `vbLf` was indeed the correct character for identifying the line break introduced by ALT + Enter. My issue turned out to be caused by how the content of `text` was ending one character before the line break, therefore the `InStr(startlocation, text, vbLf)` on that string was not finding the line break. Extending `text` (which was created using the `Mid` function) by 1 took care of the issue. So:

Instead of: `text = Mid(entryvalue, delimeterlocation, Len(entryvalue) - delimeterlocation)`

I did this: `text = Mid(entryvalue, delimeterlocation, Len(entryvalue) - delimeterlocation + 1)`